# Why does רש״י say (שבת דף לז ע״א) stoves were moveable and put on the ground?

Tags: rashi, maseches-shabbos, appliances

The *Bavli*, *[Shabas](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00879.html#HtmpReportNum0070_L2)* 37 *amud* 1, wonders about the permissibility of placing a pot of food adjacent to a stove-oven (rather than atop or in it).

> איבעיא להו מהו לסמוך בה תוכה וגבה אסור אבל לסמוך בה שפיר דמי או דילמא לא שנא

*Rashi* explains the question:

> **מהו לסמוך**. קדרה אצל דופן הכירה בלא גרופה שהכירה מטלטלת היא ומושיבים אותה על גבי קרקע׃
>
> …For a stove-oven is moveable, and they would seat it on the ground.

Huh? Why is *Rashi* telling us, here, that a stove-oven is moveable and that they would seat it on the ground? What does this have to do with the question of abutting a pot to the stove-oven? (Note that this is not the first time a stove-oven is mentioned, so *Rashi* is not describing it just for our general understanding of how it was used.)